# Creating an object within a class definition

Tags: java, android, object

What does line #4 in the code below mean? Is it supposed to be a null-parameter object of type StatusTracker being created ?

My apologies if this question is too trivial. I am new to android and have only very basic java knowledge. I have never seen an object being defined within a class body so far...

```
public class StatusTracker {
  private Map<String, String> mStatusMap;
  private List<String> mMethodList;
  private static StatusTracker ourInstance = new StatusTracker();
  private static final String STATUS_SUFFIX = "ed";

  public static StatusTracker getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
  }

  private StatusTracker() {
    mStatusMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    mMethodList = new ArrayList<String>();
  }

/* other class functions ... */

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to clear things in detail as you have just started on this,

**StatusTracker ourInstance = new StatusTracker();**

We can define objects of a class within the same class as you saw here. This is a very important property we use in many data structures.

Meaning: This means that we can hold memory address of an object with another object, such that both the objects are of same type.

**static StatusTracker ourInstance = new StatusTracker();**

defining a memeber static means, that member is associated with the class and not with any object of the class. It can be modified through class name.

**Singleton class**

```
public static StatusTracker getInstance() {
return ourInstance;
}
```

This code helps us in keeping only one object of this class throughout the program. This can be useful in cases where we want to hold centralized data for the whole program in this object.

We can access our central data from anywhere using

```
StatusTracker.getInstance()
```

Comment: Thank you varsh for taking the time for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This is a singleton object, this means only one instance of it gets created, and you can access it using `StatusTracker.getInstance()` method.

Comment: Maybe you should write StatusTracker.getInstance() to make it clearer.

Comment: I have never seen a singleton being initialized like this. Is this bad practice?

Comment: @Laksa Why would that be a bad practice?

Comment: I don't know if it is bad practice or not, but it is possible to create the instance at the first call to getInstance method, so it would be created when it is needed for the first time, resulting less memory consumption.

Comment: A common approach is `getInstance(){if(ourInstance==null){ourInstance = new StatusTracker();}return ourInstance;}`

Comment: Thank you @Utku for the keyword 'Singleton'. Now I know what I need to read up on. I had tried searching in Google with the same title but had no luck.